# How to make riding function in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

The function I want to make is kind like riding. When PlayerA jumps on playerB. They would stick with each other, and PlayerA on the top would have the control of both of them. PlayerA can move two player as a whole body. I first add a fixedjoint between two players' rigidbody, and then set the PlayerA as the parent object of playerB. This would work for most of the time. But the question of Fixjoint is that when PlayerA's speed is too fast, they would jitter so hard. Is there any way to fix this problem?

```
riderGamePlayer.transform.position = transform.position + Vector3.up * riderY;
riderGamePlayer.gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
riderGamePlayer.gameObject.GetComponent<FixedJoint>().connectedBody = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
transform.parent = riderGamePlayer.transform;
```

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may be able to parent the objects together and not use the fixed joint at all.   Set Player A directly as the parent object of PlayerB, and offset Player B using transform.localPosition.

Comment: but I want them share a same physic feedback. If playerB only attached by parent node, if any physical change applied on both of them, if would become very strange.

Comment: Do **not** parent your objects! The joint should be enough for your needs